# Conditional Formatting - Looking for cells not including two particular characters followed by two numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, string

Using Excel 2013 I'm looking to apply a conditional formatting rule to all cells in a range of a column that do not contain SD followed by two numbers, so an example would be SD01 or SD32. The column of interest is K.

I've thought I would deal with the two characters first then figure out how to add the two digits.

I came up with a formula that ignores blank cells, then highlights the ones that have SD.

The first formula I tried that highlights the correct ones (the ones with SD):

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(K12),"",(IF(SEARCH("SD",K12,1),1,0))),"")
```

I thought reversing the results of the SEARCH formula would have solved that problem:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(K12),"",(IF(SEARCH("SD",K12,1),1,""))),1)
```

If this is simpler with Office 2019, please mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do what you are looking for:

```
=NOT(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("SD",K12,1),0),K12=""))
```

[image]

---

For the more involved request (regarding the numbers after the "SD"):

```
=NOT(OR(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(K12,SEARCH("SD",K12,1)+2,2)),0),K12=""))
```

[image]

---

If values with only one digit after `SD` (e.g. `SD1`) should also be formatted, I would suggest this:

```
=NOT(OR(AND(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(K12,SEARCH("SD",K12,1)+2,1))),0),IFERROR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(K12,SEARCH("SD",K12,1)+3,1))),0)),K12=""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that made a huge difference, I'll keep using NOT in mind in the future.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Sorry for the slow response. In a meeting so... I applied it, it worked. I'll double back later to review it so I understand it.

Comment: Thanks again, I just reviewed the formula; you are set up to find the first SD then using  MID to take first value afterwards and confirm it was a number and part to the 3rd value afterwards and confirm it is a number.  Something I hadn't thought of.